# Unable to get to microservice

Tags: istio

Using

- minikube 0.23
- kubectl 1.8x
- istio 0.2.10

Enabled auto sidecar injection and started minikube with all the right addons

```
minikube start --vm-driver=xhyve --extra-config=apiserver.Admission.PluginNames="Initializers,NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,GenericAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota" --kubernetes-version=v1.7.5
```

I see the side car along side the microservice.

```
NAME                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
microse-598544478f-hs8pv   2/2       Running   2          1d
```

but I am unable to get to the patient microservice now with istio enabled.

```
export GATEWAY_URL=$(kubectl get po -n istio-system -l istio=ingress -o 'jsonpath={.items[0].status.hostIP}'):$(kubectl get svc istio-ingress -n istio-system -o 'jsonpath={.spec.ports[0].nodePort}')

curl -iv -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT $GATEWAY_URL -d '{"firstField":"firstData"}'
```

I get the following:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: 192.168.64.4:31496/
*   Trying 192.168.64.4...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.64.4 (192.168.64.4) port 31496 (#0)
> PUT / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.64.4:31496
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 84
> 
* upload completely sent off: 84 out of 84 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< date: Fri, 03 Nov 2017 13:53:31 GMT
date: Fri, 03 Nov 2017 13:53:31 GMT
< server: envoy
server: envoy
< connection: close
connection: close
< content-length: 0
content-length: 0

< 
* Closing connection 0
```

I have no problem doing this PUT without istio. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an Ingress resource for your service? You need something like this:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "istio"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /.*
        backend:
          serviceName: <your service name>
          servicePort: <your service port>
EOF
```